# Adding Polygon to a Group in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I am using Phaser 2.5.0

I am trying to add a graphics (polygon) to a group. Please see the below code for your reference.

I am getting below two javascript errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: child.setStageReference is not a function phaser.js:14661 
Uncaught TypeError: this.children[i].preUpdate is not a function phaser.js:33643
```

The error is coming from the last line this.wrongLocation.add(poly);

Can someone please let me know what could be the reason for the error.

```
this.wrongLocation = this.add.group();
this.wrongLocation.enableBody = true;

x = 360;
y = 0;

var poly = new Phaser.Polygon([ new Phaser.Point(x+64, y), new Phaser.Point(x+131, y+33), new Phaser.Point(x+66, y+64), new Phaser.Point(x, y+32) ]);
graphics = this.gathis.add.graphics(0, 0);
graphics.beginFill(0xFF33ff);
graphics.drawPolygon(poly.points);
graphics.endFill();
this.wrongLocation.add(poly);
```

Please note that I can add a sprite to a group using similar code without any problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: `graphics = this.gathis.add.graphics(0, 0);` appears to have a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`poly` is a shape. You want to add `graphics`, which is a display object:

```
this.wrongLocation.add(graphics);
```

Comment: its working correctly now. But overlap function is not working with this code. --> me.game.physics.arcade.overlap(me.taxiNE, me.wrongLocation, me.hitTheRoad); Did you know what could be the reason for this. Thanks for your help

Comment: @AugustineJoseph, is the overlap called in `create`? it should be called in `update`